# Map collection in Nodejs Harmony/ES6 broken?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-6

seems that Map in Nodejs 0.10.20 is broken. Im starting it up with the --harmony (which includes the --harmony_collections flag).
For reference check out http://dailyjs.com/2012/10/15/preparing-for-esnext/.
The examples bellow run in Firefox 20.0.

in the Nodejs console I do the following

> > var map = new Map([ ["name", "Nicholas"], ["title", "Author"]]);
>   undefined
>   > map
>   {}

so the contsructor initialization doesnt seem to work.
then I follow the Firefox examples and they mostly dont work:

> > console.log(map.has("name"));   // true
>   false
>   undefined
>   > console.log(map.get("name"));   // "Nicholas"
>   undefined
>   undefined
>   > console.log(map.has("title"));  // true
>   false
>   undefined
>   > console.log(map.get("title"));  // "Author"
>   undefined
>   undefined
>   > console.log(map.size());        // 2
>   TypeError: Object # has no method 'size'
>       at repl:1:17
>       at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
>       at repl.js:249:20
>       at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
>       at Interface. (repl.js:239:12)
>       at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
>       at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
>       at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
>       at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)

Im confused that these basic Map methods dont work. 
I have Nodejs version 0.10.20

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem /was/ even. It's a development feature. Also, don't use `console.log()`  in the REPL. The result is already inspected and dumped in the same fashion.

Comment: you need to use the whole array as a key in that code, not just an arbitrary array element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working. I tested it on node v0.10.13

```
var map = new Map();
map.set("name", "Nicholas");
map.set("title", "Author");

> map.has("name");
true
> map.get("name");
'Nicholas'
> map.has("title");
true
> map.get("title");
'Author'
```

What you are trying is specific to Mozilla. It is not implemented in V8. Amongst what you tried `size` and array intialization with constructor is not there in V8. I was not able to find good documentation for es-harmony implementation in V8, which makes it hard to work with. Also it is not a standard yet, so implementations will vary.

Comment: Correct, V8 does not yet understand the optional `iterable` argument to the `Map` constructor, which is a more recent addition to the proposal (and V8 only recently got support for iterators anyway).

Comment: ok. thanks guys. Im assuming this stuff is coming in nodejs 0.12?

Comment: @deepblue looks *highly* unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, node.js v0.10.25 Map appears to support the following methods:

```
> console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Map.prototype))
[ 'constructor', 'get', 'set', 'has', 'delete' ]
```

Very unfortunately, there does not seem to be any way to iterate over the elements in the Map.